# SQL Server 2012 - Create Data Type from existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which accepts a user-defined table type called `dbo.NodeTableType`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNonExistingNode]
    (@TableVariable dbo.NodeTableType READONLY)
```

It seems redundant, because the `dbo.NodeTableType` is identical to an actual table in my database `dbo.Nodes`.

1. Do I really have to create this data-type in order to except it as a parameter in my stored procedure?
2. If the answer to #1 is "Yes", then is there a way to create this data-type by pointing it at the table? Currently, I have to create it this way:

   ```
   CREATE TYPE NodeTableType AS TABLE 
       (NodeTypeId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        Location NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
        DisplayName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
        AccessLevel SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        IsEnabled BIT NOT NULL,
        CreatedOn DATETIME2(7) NULL,
        CreatedBy NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
        ModifiedOn DATETIME2(7) NULL,
        ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
        NativeId BIGINT NOT NULL,
        SourceId INT NOT NULL,
        Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        Alias NVARCHAR(100) NULL
   )
   ```

Comment: It isn't that difficult to create a type from a table. Just script out the table and change a couple words at the beginning. And yes you have to define the type in order to pass it. How else would sql know what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to define a user-defined table type is through `CREATE TYPE` statement according to  documentation at this URL: [User Defined Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx). So you cannot use a table for this.

*I would recommend to stick to the standard practice of passing a table valued parameter that has been created with `CREATE TYPE`*.

Another approach as outlined below can be used provided you can live without passing a table valued parameter to your procedure, and I am not sure if that is possible in your case.

In your stored procedure, you could populate a table variable of the same type as the original `NodeTableType` type. Of course, you would need to decide the logic for populating this table variable; I have assumed that the logic is something as simple as `NodeId < 10` as an example only; in your case this rule would be different and probably more complex.

```
DECLARE @myTable dbo.NodeTableType;
INSERT INTO @myTable( 
  NodeTypeId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  Location NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  DisplayName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
  AccessLevel SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  IsEnabled BIT NOT NULL,
  CreatedOn DATETIME2(7) NULL,
  CreatedBy NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
  ModifiedOn DATETIME2(7) NULL,
  ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
  NativeId BIGINT NOT NULL,
  SourceId INT NOT NULL,
  Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  Alias NVARCHAR(100) NULL) 
SELECT * from dbo.Nodes where NodeId < 10;
--now you can use @myTable rather than @TableVariable
--in your stored procedure
```